# Remove html tags before CSV generated in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have this code:

```
class ExportEvents extends Model
{
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'title_on_the_list', 'content', 'date_from', 'hour_from', 'date_to', 'hour_to', 'price', 'responsible_person', 'phone_responsible_person', 'www_responsible_person', 'email_responsible_person'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = "event_calendars";
}

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

public function downloadData(string $type = 'csv')
    {
        $data = ExportEvents::get()->toArray();
        $fileName = 'Events '.now();
        return \Excel::create($fileName, function ($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but I must remove html tags from column "content" in my csv file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to preprocess your data before you generate the Excel document. See this example code.

```
foreach($data as $i => $item){
    $content = strip_tags($item['content']);
    $data[$i]['content'] = $content;
}
```

Comment: Where can I add this?

Comment: Add it after ```$data = ExportEvents::get()->toArray();```